# Why is this one-liner joke by Neal Brennan funny?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, jokes

This one-liner comes from Neal Brennan's standup '3 Mics'. He told it around 22 mins into the act.

The joke is:

> One hundred percent of people who eat
>       in that dining section 
>       of the grocery store are murderers.

The audience apparently got it and erupted in laughter. But I did not get this oneliner.

[image]

[image]

Screenshots are provided to show that the quote in question is correct

Comment: I can only guess, but could the people possibly all be eating meat? And some (many) people consider [eating meat to be a form of murder](http://www.tennessean.com/story/magnolia/taste/2017/01/25/ode-jackson-grocery-store-plate-lunch/96731610/).

Comment: Voting to close because the question is not about the English language.

Comment: I don't agree. You are thinking in the very narrow sense of 'learning english'. To improve proficiency, it is important to understand the cultural context of a discourse or a conversation.

Comment: What is the purpose of the pictures, Anthony?  If you think they provide "context" you're mistaken. What is the antecedent  of **that section** in the sentence spoken by the comic?

Comment: I said "cultural context". The picture is to show the subtitle and to show I did not misheard. @TRomano, I'd appreciate if you let more capable people to help enlighten me. Thanks.

Comment: You did not answer my specific question. What is being referred to by "**that** dining section"?

Comment: This is a one liner. This is all there is.

Comment: The comic is implying that no sane person would want to eat at one of those tables in the dining section of a supermarket. If you see a person there, he's a psychopath. Explaining his sense of humor any further would be off-topic.

Comment: In where I live, I haven't come across dining section in any supermarket. That's why cultural context is important to understanding conversations.

Comment: But you did not ask "What is a 'dining section' at a supermarket?" You asked "Why is it funny?"  Explaining jokes is on-topic here only if the joke is a play on words.

Comment: I agree with @TRomano, what was said *before* the quoted text? I think the word "that" is important and is appealing to topics in previous sentances. Whilst the question quotes a one sentance that does not mean it is a one liner. Many jokes have several sentances of preamble followed by a one-sentance punch line.

Comment: There is also colloquial **that**, meaning "the one everyone knows about", or "the one you see everywhere".  In the US, nearly every supermarket these days has a (usually deserted) dining area with tables.

Comment: "Explaining jokes is on-topic here only if the joke is a play on words." @TRomano how would I know it is a play on words or not if I don't understand why the audience laughed at the question in the first place? (It is a rhetorical question. Don't bother to answer)

Answer (score 0):

As many people would put it:

> *It's funny because it's true! Hahahahaha!*

There's nothing inherently funny in the sentence. Maybe a bit of exaggeration (obviously not everybody dining there is a murderer), but that's it. This same sentence, said by anybody else, or said by Brennan himself but out of a comedy context, wouldn't make anybody laugh.

However, people laugh. Why? Because a comedian just said "something funny".
During their shows, stand-up comedians make use of a wide range of vocal inflexions, face gestures and other visual and auditive cues to let people know *when* they are supposed to laugh. It's part of a comedian's work; the audience knows it, and they know the cues and will readily cooperate when they have to. And more importantly, **people laugh because they want to**. They paid for a comedy show, they are in the mood of having fun and laughing, and they'll laugh at every single chance there is to (usually following the aformentioned cues).

But seriously: this doesn't really have *anything* to do with English Language Learning (despite your comments). It may have something to do with American Culture Learning, but this is not the appropiate site for questions about that.